# Top rounded corners in Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `Activity` with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` theme and I am trying to customize the dialog background. I want to be able to round the dialog corners and I am able to do that using

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_window_background</item>
</style>
```

`dialog_window_background`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:drawable="@color/white"
    android:insetTop="64dp" >

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

When I use `android:radius` the dialog corners are rounded but when I use `android:topLeftRadius` and `android:topRightRadius` the corners become square again.

Does anyone know how I can apply radius just to the top portion of the dialog?

What I am looking to do:

[image: Top Rounded corners]

**Update** It seems that if you have `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` in your style the top rounded corners don't work

Comment: is the `android:topRightRadius` shows square also in android studio preview panel?

Answer (score 1):

In my project I have used below code for custom background for alert dialog .Try this, may be it will help you

Replace your dialog_window_background.xml code with the below code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="@color/color_white" >
</solid>

<corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/d30sp"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/d30sp">
</corners>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way, add this dailog.xml inside drawable folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- From: support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_dialog_material_background_light.xml -->
    <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:insetLeft="16dp"
           android:insetTop="16dp"
           android:insetRight="16dp"
           android:insetBottom="16dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" 
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>

    </inset>
```

Add this in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!--buttons color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <!--title and message color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--dialog background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog</item>
</style>
```

add alertdialog in activity

```
AlertDialog.Builder confirmation = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    confirmation.setTitle("Title");
    confirmation.setMessage("Are you sure.?").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {

        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            });
    confirmation.show();
```

result will be alertdialog with only top corners rounded

[image: output]

Comment: Yeah I tried that too it seems if you have `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` in your style the rounded corners go away

Answer (score 1):

Try below drawable file code for shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
    android:topRightRadius="40dp"/>
<solid
    android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

</shape>
```